# Transform a dictionary to another with a different key type

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Given:

```
class KeyType1{...}
class KeyType2{...}
class ValueType{...}

public KeyType2 Lookup(KeyType1 value)
{
    // Returns a unique value of KeyType2 or otherwise, null
}
```

Is there a neat LINQ way to transform:

`IDictionary<KeyType1,ValueType>` ==> `IDictionary<KeyType2,ValueType>`

The following important points:

- No 2 values of type `KeyType1` map to the same `KeyType2`
- **edit** It is possible `Lookup` may return null i.e. the mapping may not be complete. In such cases, these entries should be omitted from the new dictionary

Comment: Note the edit: `Lookup` may return null

Comment: Updated my answer. It's a little tricky to change the requirements after people already answered. I've only accidently read this new problem (the null returning Lookup). If further changes occure, please leave me a comment :)

Comment: Yeah I added it right after, I was waiting to see if people noticed rather than post the same comment on 3 answers (they were all given very fast)

Comment: is `Lookup` an `ILookup` or an `IDictionary`?

Comment: @Jodrell `Lookup` is a method, sorry if that's not clear (feel free to edit it for legibility)

Comment: @Mr.Boy, ah okay, I edited my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, assuming `Lookup` is a function that returns a reference type that could be null.

```
b = a
    .Select(p => new { Key = Lookup(p.Key), p.Value }))
    .Where(p => p.Key != null)
    .ToDictionary(p => p.Key, p => p.Value);
```

Answer (score 1):

To avoid to need `Lookup` twice you can firstly create a `Dictionary<KeyType1, KeyType2>` to map the old keys to the new ones:

```
IDictionary<KeyType1,KeyType2> keyMap = sourceDictionary.Keys.ToDictionary(key => key, key => Lookup(key));
```

This `keyMap` now may contain `null` values for some source keys. So we filter it with `Where` and then combine them with the source dictionary to create your new dictionary:

```
IDictionary<KeyType2,ValueType> target = keyMap.Where(kvp => kvp.Value != null).
               ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Value, sourceDictionary[kvp.Key]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Where` firstly to filter the source, then use `ToDictionary` extension specifying the new key and the value:

```
var dictionary1 = new Dictionary<KeyType1, ValueType>();
var dictionary2 = dictionary1.Where(kv => Lookup(kv.Key) != null)
                             .ToDictionary(kv => Lookup(kv.Key), kv => kv.Value);
```

If you want to compute the key for those cases where `Lookup` is `null` you can do this:

```
dictionary1.ToDictionary(kv => Lookup(kv.Key) ?? ComputeNewKey(kv.Key),
                         kv => kv.Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Dictionary<string, string> StringDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
 Dictionary<int, string> IntDict = new Dictionary<int, string>();


StringDict.ToList().ForEach(D =>
{
    IntDict.Add(Convert.ToInt32(D.Key), D.Value);
});
```